# What does it mean practically "An ActorSystem is a heavyweight structure that will allocate 1...N Threads, so create one per logical application"?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

What does it mean practically "create one per logical application"? I have an enterprise application in Scala with 5 modules that will be deployed independently. I have used ActorSystem.create("...") to create some 4 or 5 system Actors in each modules like Messaging, Financial, Sales, Workflow, Security.

Do I have to do ActorSystem.create("...") only once? for my enterprise application with 5 modules as above.
Or am I doing it correctly?

Comment: It practically means that if you can reuse same thread-pools and akka-system configuration - it's better to use one actor system

Answer (score 2):

It practically means that if you can reuse same thread-pool**s**, akka-system configuration, dead-letters, namespace for actors, event buses - it's better to use one actor system.

So, in your case, module - is the logical application. Some frameworks like OSGi may allow several logical modules to live inside one JVM (physical application), that's probably why "logical application" term was used. However, in most cases (like, I suppose, yours) they are equal - I would recommend you to use one `ActorSystem` per module.

More generally, tha case of several logical applications inside one physical is some meta-container (like servlet-container), that runs inside one JVM but manages several independent applications (like several deployed `.war`s) living in the same JVM.

Btw, if you want to manage JVM resources correctly - you can just assign different dispatchers (and maybe thread pools) into different logical groups of actors, and still use one actor-system. So the rule is - if you can use one `ActorSystem` - just use one. [Entities must not be multiplied beyond necessity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)

P.S. You should also be aware of [lookup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/axgJcLkCRpU) problem when using multiple actor-systems in one physical application. So if solution proposed there seems like workaround for your architecture - it's also a sign to merge systems together.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a scenario/context where we cannot reuse same thread-pools, akka-system configuration, dead-letters, namespace for actors, event buses, so that I can understand where I can re-use and how many actor systems I need to create in my context.

Comment: @ceecer1 OSGi was such example - every module inside OSGi container has its own classpath, so there is no natural way to share resources. You can still do it by adding common dependency, but then your modules are gonna became overcupled as this dependency is considered as a library then (libraries should not create heavy objects by themselves). As it was said in first place - your case seems pretty simple - you need only one Akka system per application.

Comment: @ceecer1 more generally if your modules can't directly communicate inside one JVM, which means that you havesome meta-application (container) for several different appplications, like several web-applications (different `.war`s) inside one web-server - then you've got no other choice than using several Akka systems. If you can use only one - use only one :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong size here, or a magic formula to do it right.

It depends on the things you want you ActorSystem(s) to achieve and how the application parts relate to each other.

You should separate ActorSystems when they behave largely differenting performance and reliability needs and when the systems behave differently (blocking/ non blocking for example).

A good example would be a typical WebApplication with a Database: The application handling requests could be non blocking (like for example play), the database driver could be blocking (like slick in the old times). 
So here it would be a good idea to use separated ActorSystems, to still be able to handle requests to inform the user that the dataabse communication is down.

As everything each ActorSystem comes with a cost, so you should only do it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

As @dk14 and @Andreas have already said an ActorSystem allows you to share resources ( thread-pools, akka-system configuration, dead-letters, namespace for actors, event buses).

From a sharing perspective it makes sense to have one ActorSystem per JVM and have different dispatchers per logical module. To get the most out of the your Akka actors it is critical that you tune your dispatcher settings to match 1) your application workload 2) your hardware settings (# of cores). For example, if you have some actors doing network IO they should have their own dedicated dispatchers.

You should also consider carefully how many JVMs you want to run on a physical node. For example, if you have a host with 256/512 GB of RAM running a single JVM may not be the best configuration. On the other hand, a physical/VM having 64 GB of RAM will do fine with just one JVM instance